# How to see files in branch created on local repo on EC2?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I have created git repository from one of the folders on EC2(local repo). Then I created a branch on local repo(without cloning, just did `git checkout -b *branch_name*`). When you create a branch on github, you can see all the files contained in that branch. But I am not able to see the files in the branch created on local repo using above command. I also do not see anything under `.git --> branches` in local repo. How do I explore files in branch without cloning it? (Also, confuses how clonning is different than creating branch, reading all the material is not helping.)

Comment: Cloning is getting the repository (all the object of the repository), creating a branch is just adding a tree object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git ls-tree` like:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only *branch_name*
```